# _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)) returns null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, argumentnullexception

I am having an issue with Claims not populating with ClaimsPrinciple after creating a JWT. I am using ASP.NET Core 6 on VS 2022. The issue raised after configuring identity to include Roles and RolesUsers. I had no issues prior to including these 2 identity tables from the automated generated ones from IdentityModel.

now on creation, I show no errors and receive the JWT token without any issues, but afterwards when I try to authorize the user that log in the ClaimIdentity does not propagate and errors on _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)) showing null.

Here is some code to show the current state of the project.

First is the Method that handles the validation for login users.

```
       [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> GetCurrentUser()
        {

            // Null Exception Error
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email));

            return CreateUserObject(user);
        }

        UserDto CreateUserObject( AppUser user )
        {
            return new UserDto
            {
                DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                Image = null,
                Token = _tokenService.CreateToken(user),
                Username = user.UserName
            };
        }
```

This is my Token Service that handles creating the JWT token from users that Register or Login.

```
    public class TokenService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public TokenService(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public string CreateToken(AppUser user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["TokenKey"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7.0),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
```

This is what I changed prior to having this issue in my IdentityServiceExtension Class.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(opt => //Changed AddIdentityCore to AddIdentity to apply AppUser & AppRole
            {
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
                .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<AppRole>>(); //Added Role Manager for Roles to loaded.


            var Key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"]));

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = Key,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });

            services.AddScoped<TokenService>();

            // Added Roles to Policy
            services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("Verified", pol => 
                    pol.RequireRole("User", "Staff", "Admin", "Guest"));
                opt.AddPolicy("Restricted", pol =>
                    pol.RequireRole("User", "Staff", "Admin"));
                opt.AddPolicy("EmployeeAccess", pol =>
                    pol.RequireRole("Staff", "Admin"));
                opt.AddPolicy("ManagerAccess", pol =>
                    pol.RequireRole("Admin"));
            });
            //////////////////////

            return services;
        }
```

Hopefully this is enough information to help me with this issue. I have searched all over online and the resolutions I have seen does not match to my particular issue to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I surprisingly found the issue, so the reason I was having errors was due to not configuring Identity to handle all Identity Models. Prior to my change, I only handled users, but by adding roles and roleusers I had to handle all of Identity Model to prevent losing the claims. Due to this fact, I had to install another Microsoft Package,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI, to gain access to the Identity Helper Method (.AddDefaultIdentity()) to configure the generated identity tables. Once added, Identity was fully configured and the issue was resolved. I hope anyone else that need help can use this as a possible solution.